# How to retrieve the JSON object key which having numbered name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to pass a number of JSON objects from my server which have names appended with a number to differentiate each other.

I am getting a problem while retrieving these objects. It is unable to append a number with its common name.

Objects look like this:

```
  {"shareInfo":[{"uname1":"abc","uname2":"sds","uname3":"uuh",.....}]}
```

I tried appending an `integer` variable to it.

```
 data.shareInfo[i].uname+''+i;
```

But it is not reading the variable together. I mean it is not taking it like `uname0,uname1,...`

Please anyone tell me how to append the number to retrieve the data, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.shareInfo[i]["uname" + i]` should work.

It's worth noting that your example data only contains one array element in data.shareInfo, so what you might actually need is:

`data.shareInfo[0]["uname" + i]`

But I can't tell which would be correct from your test data.

Comment: I edited my answer as I didn't notice uname wasn't a variable, but a string literal.  Try that version.